# Site Permissions Flyout Menu

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, security, site

I'm curious why site permissions load on some sites and not others. This particular one doesn't show anybody but on another site, it shows Owners, Members and Visitor group memberships

[image]

Comment: Are the groups named in SharePoint's standard convention (e.g. [site name] Authors, [site name] Visitors, etc.)?

Comment: The Visitors group is missing. but trying to recreate it I get an error - "The specified name is already in use"

Comment: That can't be it though because on another site the flyout is empty but the 3 default groups remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site permissions menu is available in **modern experience**, no matter what the site template is.

You are possibly looking at the menu of a site that is not supported to connect Office 365 group, for example, **publishing portal**. The SharePoint groups (*Owners, Members, Visitors*) are automatically created in User Information list but will not be listed under Site Permissions Flyout Menu.

See the comparisons below:

[image]